# Purple screen after installing to external hard drive

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, external-hdd

I have Windows 7 64 on my laptop (MSI GX660).  I downloaded the 64 bit Ubuntu 12.10 install onto a 1GB USB drive, rebooted, and installed onto a 1TB USB external HDD.  I followed [this guide](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/07/23/dual-boot-ubuntu-12-04-and-windows-7-on-a-computer-with-2-hard-drives/)

I then set the boot priority in the BIOS to the external.  Once it gets to the purple menu where I can choose "Ubuntu", I do and it goes to a purple screen and stays there.  Choosing Ubuntu recovery gives the same result.  I've tried typing "e" to edit and changing certain lines to "nomodeset" and others, doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an external hard drive to boot from remember that the read / write speeds of anything external are slower than they would be for an internal.

Your waiting time for any operating system that is stored on an external hard drive or USB pen is going to be at least double of that if you had the operating system installed on an internal hard drive.

Your best option would have been to install it onto an internal hard drive by itself or even dual boot Windows 7 & Ubuntu.  If you decided to dual boot then you would be able to remove the partition of Ubuntu if you decided you did not want it.

Hope this helped